# Admob ads failed to load in android

Tags: android, admob, native-ads, google-ads-api

I am trying to add Native Ads in my android app. But I am continually getting error Failed to load ad with error code 3.
I have tried it with other test Ad units and in that case my code is working fine, ads are displaying. 
But when I am trying to show Banner Ads from same account, I am getting error code 0. I am not able to display any type of ad from my account.

Note:- I have created this account 3 days before and Billing is also enabled and verified in this.

Comment: If you are receiving test ads then your implementation is fine. Just wait a few hours and see if you are able to receive live ads then. If not then send your Ad Unit ID to google."

Answer (score 0):

Error Code 3 :  means **ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL** (The ad request was successful, but no ad was returned due to lack of ad inventory). Wait for few hours/days, then you will able to receive live ads.

Error Code 0 :  means **ERROR_CODE_INTERNAL_ERROR** (Something happened internally; for instance, an invalid response was received from the ad server) may be you are using native ads id in banner ad.

Comment: I just re-checked the banner ad id, its correct. Same thing happen here also i.e test ads working fine but ad unit from my account is not working :(

Comment: in case of native ads getting error code 3 and in case of banner ads getting 0